# Creating a mixin for theme colours

Tags: sass

I have set a body class as a handle to target pages and apply the correct colours via my stylesheet. The body class is for example `<body class="theme-red">` and I currently have the following classes set up in my scss file:

```
.theme-border-colors {
    .theme-tourquoise & {
        border-color:$turquoise;
    }
    .theme-red & {
        border-color:$red;
    }
    .theme-yellow & {
        border-color:$yellow;
    }
    .theme-green & {
        border-color:$green;
    }
    .theme-blue & {
        border-color:$blue;
    }
    .theme-brown & {
        border-color:$brown;
    }
    .theme-pink & {
        border-color:$pink;
    }
}
.theme-background-colors {
    .theme-tourquoise & {
        background-color:$turquoise;
    }
    .theme-red & {
        background-color:$red;
    }
    .theme-yellow & {
        background-color:$yellow;
    }
    .theme-green & {
        background-color:$green;
    }
    .theme-blue & {
        background-color:$blue;
    }
    .theme-brown & {
        background-color:$brown;
    }
    .theme-pink & {
        background-color:$pink;
    }
}
.theme-font-colors {
    .theme-tourquoise & {
        color:$turquoise;
    }
    .theme-red & {
        color:$red;
    }
    .theme-yellow & {
        color:$yellow;
    }
    .theme-green & {
        color:$green;
    }
    .theme-blue & {
        color:$blue;
    }
    .theme-brown & {
        color:$brown;
    }
    .theme-pink & {
        color:$pink;
    }
}
```

Can a mixin be made to incorporate all 3 of these when needed in my scss files. I current `@extend .theme-font-colors` etc.

Comment: What is wrong with what you currently have if you know it works?

Comment: Nothing! Just wondered if it was more efficient or possible for it to be a mixin? Extending all three classes works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can create list of name and colors. Checkout this code:

```
$border-colors: black #333333, red #ff0000, white #ffffff; 
$background-colors: black #333333, red #ff0000, white #ffffff; 

@mixin list-parser($var){
  @each $item in $var {
    .theme-#{nth($item, 1)} & {
        border-color: nth($item, 2);
    }
  }
}

.theme-border-colors {
  @include list-parser($border-colors);
}

.theme-background-colors {
  @include list-parser($background-colors);
}
```